# Is there a list of Typescript types specific to React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

It seems like this should be out there; a list, with explanations, of at least the most common Typescript types specific to React. For example, something explaining JSX.Element, React.ReactNode, React.FunctionComponent, React.FunctionComponentElement, etc., and where they apply.

Browsing index.d.ts at DefinitelyTyped is the closest I've found, but is a bit much for someone who's relatively new to Typescript.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [this repo](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet) and [its web](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/setup)

Comment: https://www.saltycrane.com/cheat-sheets/typescript/react/latest/